# FB.Api error on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I got error to get facebook name on Unity 3D, this function clearly working 2 weeks ago,

FB.Init(this.InitCallback, this.OnHideUnity);

```
private void InitCallback ()
{
    if (FB.IsInitialized) {

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {

           FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<string>() { "public_profile","email" }, this.AuthCallback);

        } else {
        }
    } else {

        Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
    }
}

 private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {

        FB.API("/me?fields=name", HttpMethod.GET, this.LoginCallback2);

    } else {
        //Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}
void LoginCallback2(IResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null) {

        Debug.Log(result.Error);

    }
    else{
        fbid = result.ResultDictionary ["id"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I got error on LoginCallback2 function, debug as follow:

```
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
connect:LoginCallback2(IResult) (at Assets/connect.cs:983)
Facebook.Unity.<Start>d__9:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that either FB hasn't been initialized, or the user is NOT logged in. Below I have shared my own code for retrieving the User's full name and their FBID. You will want to check to make sure that the following is true before calling this code section:

FB.IsInitialized == true

and

FB.IsLoggedIn == true

```
    if (result != null) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error)) {
            if (result.ResultDictionary != null)
                if (result.ResultDictionary.ContainsKey("name")) {
                    result.ResultDictionary.TryGetValue("name", out Name);
                }
            if (result.ResultDictionary != null)
                if (result.ResultDictionary.ContainsKey("id")) {
                    result.ResultDictionary.TryGetValue("id", out FBID);
                }
        }
    }
```